# Where iptables store rules on Ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables

i am runing ubuntu server lts 12.04 on my server and i want to see all rules specified with iptables. When i run iptables -L i get list of rules, but becouse i dont use any interfaces i can not see all of them becouse i can not scroll up and down.
I had make research about is there any file where iptables store rules but i could not find any usefull information. Becouse of that i am writing my question here:

Where iptables store its rules? or is there any way to see rules on black screen one by one?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: `iptables -L | less` to scroll through the output?

Comment: Thank you Barmar, it was usefull. But still i am locking for a file where the rules are stored. Becouse list is long.

Comment: Try asking on unix.stackexchange.com or a Linux-specific forum.

Comment: Tank you Barmar, i will try there. Also i want to ask am i doing something wrong here? someone woted down my question.

Comment: Maybe because it's off-topic for SO.

Comment: On Ubuntu, `iptables` by default loads its rules from `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` at startup.  Note, however, that the file does not automatically update when you make a live change.

Comment: Cross-site sort-of-duplicate that's probably useful to anyone landing here: https://askubuntu.com/q/117155/119754

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iptables itself does not store the current rules in a file. it just configures the tables in the kernel.

anyway you can create a snapshot of the current ruleset with

```
iptables-save > /path/to/file
```

and restore it later with

```
iptables-restore < /path/to/file
```

Comment: ... and from where does `iptables` load these configurations when Ubuntu boots up?

Comment: @Abdull By default, nowhere. There are no `iptables` rules configured by default, nor is there any default location at which Ubuntu looks for them. You need to bootstrap such a system yourself by making `iptables-restore` run on boot, as described at https://askubuntu.com/q/117155/119754.